# What is the relation between Information , Information Object and Data Model

Tags: aris

What is the relation between *Information , Information Object and Data Model* .

Comment: I doubt that tagging this with UML is correct since `Information` is simply too general and neither `Information Object` nor `Data Model` are known UML entities.

Comment: I removed the UML tag. This seem to be rather ARIS-specific terms.